# Null check operator used on a null value faced in profile picture ternary operation

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am tryinng to create a profile page, in which the user gets to upload a new image for profile. The user can login using either his google account or sign up normally.

When he registers using email-password method, a standard image is used for it instead.
I'm facing an issue in this. Can you please help me with this?

declaration

```
  File? image;
```

This is the code for the profile:

```
image != null
                    ? CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 64,
                        backgroundImage: FileImage(image!),
                      )
                    : const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 64,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"),
                      ),
```

Comment: Try this 
`backgroundImage: FileImage(image ?? ""),`

Answer (score 0):

When user sign ups using **email password** method, you can upload a default profile photo for that in the `firebase firestore` and use that instead, that way if the user wants to update their profile photo, you can easily replace it in the firebase firestore and show that on the screen itself

Comment: I'm doing that tbh. The user has a field called, photoURL which is responsible for storing the URL of the photo. Once a user uploads a  new image, it gets uploaded in the storage, a new URL is generated and replaced in the user's document.

Comment: Then I think you can disply it using `NetworkImage` instead of using `FileImage`.